# Need help migrating from Spark 2.0 to Spark 3.1 - Accumulable to AccumulatorV2

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, kylo, spark3

I'm working on adding `Spark 3.1` and `Scala 2.12` support for [**Kylo Data-Lake Management Platform**](https://kylo.io/).

I need help with migrating the following functions:

```java
    /**
     * Creates an {@link Accumulable} shared variable with a name for display in the Spark UI.
     */
    @Nonnull
    static <R, P1> Accumulable<R, P1> accumulable(@Nonnull final R initialValue, @Nonnull final String name, @Nonnull final AccumulableParam<R, P1> param,
                                                  @Nonnull final KyloCatalogClient<Dataset<Row>> client) {
        return ((KyloCatalogClientV2) client).getSparkSession().sparkContext().accumulable(initialValue, name, param);
    }
```

```java
/**
     * Applies the specified function to the specified field of the data set.
     */
    @Nonnull
    static Dataset<Row> map(@Nonnull final Dataset<Row> dataSet, @Nonnull final String fieldName, @Nonnull final Function1 function, @Nonnull final DataType returnType) {
        final Seq<Column> inputs = Seq$.MODULE$.<Column>newBuilder().$plus$eq(dataSet.col(fieldName)).result();
        final UserDefinedFunction udf = new UserDefinedFunction(function, returnType, Option$.MODULE$.<Seq<DataType>>empty());
        return dataSet.withColumn(fieldName, udf.apply(inputs));
    }
```

Can be found in [here](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/integrations/spark/spark-catalog/spark-catalog-spark-v2/src/main/java/com/thinkbiganalytics/kylo/catalog/spark/sources/DataSetProviderUtilV2.java#L52-L60) and [here](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/integrations/spark/spark-catalog/spark-catalog-spark-v2/src/main/java/com/thinkbiganalytics/kylo/catalog/spark/sources/DataSetProviderUtilV2.java#L91-L99)

I'm adding a new maven module `kylo-spark-catalog-spark-v3` to support `apache-spark:3.1.2` and `scala:2.12.10` at time of writing this.

I'm having trouble in:

1. Creating an instance of `AccumulatorV2` as the deprecation notice on the `Accumulable` class is not very clear.
   here's my attempt at the first function - **NOT COMPILING**:

```java
    @Nonnull
    static <R, P1> AccumulatorV2<R, P1> accumulable(@Nonnull final R initialValue, @Nonnull final String name, @Nonnull final AccumulatorV2<R, P1> param,
                                                  @Nonnull final KyloCatalogClient<Dataset<Row>> client) {
        AccumulatorV2<R, P1> acc = AccumulatorContext.get(AccumulatorContext.newId()).get();
        acc.register(((KyloCatalogClientV3) client).getSparkSession().sparkContext(), new Some<>(name), true);
        return acc;
    }
```

2. Creating an instance of UDF in the second function, the `UserDefinedFunction` seems to complain that it cannot be instanciated as its an abstract class.
   here's my attempt at the second function - **COMPILING** but not sure if makes sense:

```java
    /**
     * Applies the specified function to the specified field of the data set.
     */
    @Nonnull
    static Dataset<Row> map(@Nonnull final Dataset<Row> dataSet, @Nonnull final String fieldName, @Nonnull final Function1 function, @Nonnull final DataType returnType) {
        final Seq<Column> inputs = Seq$.MODULE$.<Column>newBuilder().$plus$eq(dataSet.col(fieldName)).result();
        final UserDefinedFunction udf = udf(function, returnType);
        return dataSet.withColumn(fieldName, udf.apply(inputs));
    }
```

Can you please advice me on how to get this right, or if there's docs out there that is close to this case.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. `accumulable`

---

Older versions of Spark had two APIs for accumulators: [Accumulable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/Accumulable.html) (when input and output types where different) and [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/Accumulator.html) (when input and output types are the same, i.e., `Accumulable<T,T>`).
To create an `Accumulable<OUT, IN>` instance you needed an `AccumulableParam<OUT, IN>` that defined "merge" operation (OUT+OUT), "add" operation (OUT+IN) and zero value of type OUT.

[AccumulatorV2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.html) is organised differently. It's an abstract class that needs to be extended with `add` and `merge` operations; and an understanding of what is zero value. You can see an example implementation of [CollectionAcumulator](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.scala#L451) in Spark's source code.

Responsibility of `accumulable` function changes with AccumulatorV2 API. It doesn't need to create accumulator anymore. It just needs to register it in SparkContext with a give name. I think the following would make sense:

```java
@Nonnull
static <R, P1> AccumulatorV2<P1, R> accumulable(
    @Nonnull final R initialValue, // unused
    @Nonnull final String name,
    @Nonnull final AccumulatorV2<P1, R> acc,
    @Nonnull final KyloCatalogClient<Dataset<Row>> client
) {
    ((KyloCatalogClientV2) client).getSparkSession().sparkContext().register(acc, name);
    return acc;
}
```

A few things to note:

- Order of types in class signature changed: Accumulable<OUT, IN> vs AccumulatorV2<IN, OUT>
- `initialValue` needs to be passed to an accumulator at creation time. However, you need to make sure that `copyAndReset` returns a new accumulator with zero value and not `initialValue`.
  Alternatively, you need to add a value of type P1 that after adding to the accumulator results in accumulator returning expected initial value of type R. It's not a very good idea, just an alternative.
- Also, don't use `AccumulatorContext`, because as per documentation it's

> An internal class used to track accumulators by Spark itself.

### 2. `map`

---

I think your function is correct and makes sense. Between Spark v2.0 and v3.1 `UserDefinedFunction` changed to an abstract class and now you instantiate it with [udf function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2653201b0a50a651ebc0c4e1fabb47d32dee77c4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L5119) ( `import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf`)

Comment: Thanks for the support! Yea, I noticed the `IN/OUT` parameters were swapped. This is exactly what I needed to know.